# Are there 3x3 matrices in DirectX 11?

Tags: c++, directx11, hlsl

I have a parameter in HLSL shader in a constant buffer which is a `float3x3`. Is there is 3x3 matrix struct in Directx 11 or should I use 4x4 matrix instead, and if so, how?

Comment: Be aware that a 3x3 matrix is not going to pack well into a cbuffer; trying to save storage in this manner is often a false optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D3D11 itself doesn't have any matrix structures at all; you might be thinking of the [DirectXMath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437833(v=vs.85).aspx) library's matrix classes. It *does* have a [3x3 matrix type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.xmfloat3x3(v=vs.85).aspx) you can use.

In general, you can store a 3x3 matrix in the upper-left of a 4x4 matrix (setting the bottom-right-most element to 1) *if* that 3x3 is only storing scale and/or rotation in 3D. If you were storing a 2D translation in there or anything else, you'd have to rebuild the 4x4 matrix appropriately based on whatever data you were putting into the 3x3 matrix.